# How to show upto 4 blocks and after that on click on button show all blocks?

Tags: jquery, html

I have some blocks and initially i need to show only 4 blocks.
After on click of button need to show all blocks.can anybody help here.

```js
var div_count = $('div').length; //7

$div = $('div');

$div.each(function() {
  var $divs = $(this).children();
  if ($divs.length > 5) {
    $div.children(':nth-of-type(n+5)').hide();
  }
});

$('button').click(function() {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>

<button>View All</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) function to hide all other divs except first four and show all after click on button, see below

```js
$(function(){
  $('div:gt(3)').hide(); // hide all divs after four
  $('button').on('click', function(){
   $('div').show(); // show all divs
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div>

<button>View All</button>
```

Comment: happy to help you :)